# Express 4 middleware not calling routes on DigitalOcean server

Tags: express, nginx, digital-ocean, io.js

I'm messing around with creating an API with io.js and Express 4, and I have no idea why this isn't working. I am currently running the program on a DigitalOcean droplet (Ubuntu 14.04) and it is not calling the next() method never gets called/executed. The program is being routed to by a reverse proxy with nginx at `https://<redacted>/asdf`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Request received.");
    next();
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Route /login accessed');
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log("Server started on port " + port + ".");
```

When I run the program on my droplet and send a POST request to `https://<redacted>/asdf/login`, the console prints out "Request received" but does not print out "Route /login accessed". The odd thing is that this works perfectly fine on my local machine when a post request is sent to `http://localhost:3000/login`. Is there something I am doing wrong or is this a known thing that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express uses the request's `url` property when mapping routes, and I suspect that your nginx reverse proxy isn't removing the `/asdf` root from it. If so, your url's path would be `/asdf/login` which would explain why your `/login` post handler isn't being invoked. To test this hypothesis you could try adding the reverse proxy root to your `use` like this:

```
app.use('/asdf', router);
```

If this is the case, to fix this problem, you can configure nginx to rewrite the url for you like this

```
location  /asdf {
  rewrite /asdf(.*) $1  break;
  proxy_pass         http://localhost:3200;
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

More details:
https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue. I'll apply the changes for nginx as well.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rewrite /asdf(.*) $1  break;` without the slash. That worked for me.